# Global Variable pulled from App Delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use a variable integer throughout multiple methods in my view controller. The secondsLeft variable works fine, but the otherNumber variable won't work. I get the error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant. Any ideas on how I am supposed to do this? THank you!

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize countDown,Timerlbl;

int secondsLeft = 500;

int otherNumber =[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate otherNumber];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared `otherNumber` as a global variable and the compiler expects the initial assignment to be a compile-time constant. `[delegate otherNumber]` results in a selector invocation and this is not a compile-time constant.

The solution is to move the assignment into code. For example:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        otherNumber = [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate otherNumber];
    }

    return self;
}
```

As another note, global variables are generally inadvisable in Objective-C. `@property` values are generally more recommended. Not only that, your `ViewController` class now has a dependency with your `AppDelegate`. Since your `AppDelegate` most likely is the one responsible for instantiating your `ViewController`, consider having it inject in the value of `otherNumber`. For example:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) int otherNumber;
@end

- (id)initWithSomeNumber:(int)otherNumber
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.otherNumber = otherNumber;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: How do I get the app delegate to inject the value - does this code go in my app delegate?

Comment: In your app delegate, when instantiating your `ViewController`, do it like so `viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithSomeNumber:23849];`. You'll need to expose `initWithSomeNumber` in the public `@interface` of `ViewController.`

Comment: I agreed in this case perhaps global variables are not necessary if ViewController was instantiated directy from AppDelegate itself.  Also the otherNumber was only being used from within a single class (ViewController) as the OP has stated.  But the use of global variables are still a viable option for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `AppDelegate` is the name of your app delegate class?

Have you tried adding an import for your AppDelegate, like this...

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable like this because the compiler can't create an instance of `AppDelegate` and ask it what the value of `otherNumber` should be.

Depending on how it's being used, it might be better not to define the `otherNumber` variable at all, and instead retrieve it from `AppDelegate` each time it is used. This might mean a little more typing, but it does mean you'll always get the latest correct value of `otherNumber`

Also, it's a good idea in general to use `NSInteger` instead of `int` when defining integer variables.